# C++, putting vector data into a .csv file

Tags: c++, vector

I'm working on something simple, and i want it to be able to take everything within a vector and put it into a .CSV file, where every row would be a new vector and the columns being each position within the vector.

This is my current code, however whenever I open the CSV file it is completely empty.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("test.csv");

    vector<int> arrayOne = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };


    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOne.size(); i++)
    {
        myfile << arrayOne.at(i) << ",";
    }

    cin.ignore();
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you close your program forcefully (e.g. by closing the terminal with `[x]` button) when it's stuck on `cin.ignore()`? If so, the problem is probably that the buffer of `myfile` doesn't get flushed. You either need to let your program end normally (by pressing `enter` twice) or do `myfile.close()` before `cin.ignore()`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you are totally right. I want to add, that you have to call `myfile.close()` for a clean and save exit. It is good practice. Don't rely on the operating system doing your job.

Comment: @skratchi.at More like "the destructor of `ostream` doing my job".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat doesn't matter who should do it. just don't rely on anybody else, or be sure what you do =) but thanks for the correction

Comment: Unfortunately the destructor of `ostream` can't do your job of error checking. It is good practice to call `myfile.close()` because it gives you a chance to check for errors after the write buffer has been flushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the marked answer is totally correct in the function it demands from OP, but is derivatives in the code drastically. Which can result in an undebugable code or alter the behavior OP intended. pls consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

// removed "using namespace std"

int main()
{
    std::ofstream myfile; // added "std::"
    myfile.open("test.csv");

    std::vector<int> arrayOne { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOne.size(); i++) { // added "{"
        myfile << arrayOne.at(i) << ",";
    } // added "{"

    myfile.close(); // <- note this correction!!
    std::cin.ignore(); // added this
    std::cin.ignore(); // added this
    return 0;
}
```

- consider not using `using namespace std`. This namespace includes hundreds of thousand of functions. you may collide with one of them and this is a pain to debug.
- The marked answer removes the parentheses `{}` at the `for-loop`. NEVER do that, you may run into undebugable problems, when you add one line to your `for-loop`. This line is no executed in the loop.
- The answer also remove vital code from the OP twice: `std::cin.ignore();`

Answer (score -2):

Close your file like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("test.csv");

    vector<int> arrayOne = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOne.size(); i++)
        myfile << arrayOne.at(i) << ",";

    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The point here is, output streams are often buffered. When you close the file, `close()` function ensures, any pending output sequence is written to the file.